# Find pixel coordinates in an input image in keypoint matching algorithm using opencv?

Tags: opencv, sift, surf, template-matching, keypoint

I want to find out a given image in an input image......first I used template matching using opencv but its not giving proper result. So I switched to keypoint matching using SIFT with opencv. But I am not able to find pixel location in a input image. Someone please help me I am looking everywhere but not able to solve my problem

Comment: Whats your trying code?

Comment: use matcher and compute a homography between template and input image. The object location then is the center of your template transformed to your input image.

Answer (score 1):

It is a multifaceted problem. Its easier to help with specific questions or problems.

[This tutorial on Youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zjxWpKCQqJc&t=641s) helped me with this problem.